# parsing a php value

Tags: php, arrays

for example:

```
$value_array = array("fu" => "bar", "banana" => "apple");
```

for example:

```
echo $value_array["fu"]; # output will be bar
```

okay, i have this value:

```
$value = "fuu:bar:12:apple";
```

okay, i'd like to parse the $value and write "bar" value to the screen, but i don't know how i can do this job.

Comment: Where does `"fuu:bar:12:apple"` come from?

Comment: @FelixKling, it comes from mysql table

Comment: Your `$value` reminds me serialized string. Does it actual `$value` value?

Comment: OK, what I actually want to know is how do you create this value in the first place? Instead of creating your own format, you could e.g. use `serialize` and `unserialize`.

Comment: @FelixKling, mate, thanks for your help. i solved my problem. btw, thanks for your kindly suggestion. my friend, i cam creating mysql table with my hand. value comes from mysql table. anyway, regards mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

Answer (score 3):

umm, why delimit by :? It'd be a lot easier with `fuu:bar;12:apple` but to go with what you have...

```
$value = explode(':',$value);
$values = array();
foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
   if ($k %2 != 0)
      $values[$value[($k - 1)]] = $v;
}
```

Comment: Dammit! Exactly the solution I had. Good one.

Comment: Don't you love when that happens?

Comment: No, but yes because now you get free rep :-)

Comment: haha, I like seeing my function submitted seconds before I submit it.

Comment: The thing that gets me is all the answers that are just pastes of code get all the upvotes, whereas my nicely written and explained answer just gets told to go and stand in the corner. Sort of an [okay](http://s3.amazonaws.com/kym-assets/photos/images/original/000/099/741/OkayGuy.jpg?1297653524) moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
$bar_val  = explode(":", $value);

echo $bar_val[1];
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/pyoyfk8n

Comment: How does your answer satisfy the `echo $value_array["fu"];` example?

Comment: @mario -- the OP did not ask for that, that was just an example. The OP asked how he/she would output `bar` from the given string

Comment: Question title says parsing. Nowhere does it assert that it's actually an ordered list.